# Quasar router beforeEach is stuck in loop

Tags: vue.js, router, quasar

I have below code in my router/index.js. If Token is null, I am getting this error `Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
const Router = new VueRouter({
    ...
})
Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const token = Cookies.getItem('token')
    if (token === null) {
      Router.push('/login')
    } else {
      next()
    }
})

return Router
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check the current route `if (token == null && to.name != 'login')`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this :

```
if (token === null) {
  Router.push('/login')
}
```

Navigation guards according to documents.

```
if (token === null && to.name !== 'login') {
  next({
    path: '/login'
  })
}
```

You can also send router to it's name : `next({name: 'login'})`

Refer this : [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)

And make sure you exported your router :

```
export default Router
```

Comment: WIth next i am getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property '$router' of undefined`